# How to update select option datatable laravel for current row or id

Tags: javascript, laravel, datatable

i have problem to update selected option .The database can be update ,but it update for all data .i just want to update current row only

> javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#table_refund').on('change' ,'select', function() {

    var data= $(this).closest('tr');    
    var status = $('option:selected',this).val();
 
    alert(status);
   
     $.ajax({
      type: "get",
      url: "/financial/approve/refund",
      
      data: {status: status },
      dataType: "JSON",
      success: function (response) {
        $('.alert').show();
        
      }
    });
});
```

> controller:

```
 public function studentrefund(Request $req)
 {
    //update table 

    data = Refund::find($req->userid);
    $data->status = $req->status;
    $data->save();
    return response()->json(['success'=>'Saved successfully.']);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You Need to check particular Id and that userID so you get current row.

> Controller::

```
  public function studentrefund(Request $req)
  {
    //update table 

    $data = Refund::where('id',$req->id)->where('userid',$req->userid)->first();
    $data->status = $req->status;
    $data->save();
    return response()->json(['success'=>'Saved successfully.']);
 }
```

Comment: it display error ErrorException Creating default object from empty value

Comment: Because $data is Empty or $data have not status Values , please check first check you get data in $data Or Not

Answer (score 0):

You can Use fundOrFail the findOrFail and firstOrFail methods will retrieve the first result of the query. However, if no result is found, a Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException will be thrown laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#retrieving-single-models

```
public function studentrefund(Request $req)
{
  //validate user id

  request()->validate([
    'userid' => 'required',
   ]);

  //update table 
  

  $data = Refund::findOrFail($req->userid);
  $data->status = $req->status;
  $data->save();
  return response()->json(['success'=>'Saved successfully.']);
}
```

Comment: it still update for all row not current row only

Comment: @bilaProgrammer please try now i have added the validation so that empty user id is not accepted and the reason  for update for all row is userid is empty

Comment: that's true ,display errors: {userid: ["The userid field is required."]}
message: "The given data was invalid."

Comment: @bilaProgrammer please handle the validation in your blade file and accept it if you got you answer.

Answer (score 0):

option :

```
<select id="table_refund">
    <option data-id="{{ $row->id }}" value="Aktive">Test Data</option>
</select>
```

Jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#table_refund').on('change', 'select', function() {

        var id = $(this).data('id');
        var status = $('option:selected', this).val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{{ url('financial/approve/refund') }}",
            data: {
                "id": id,
                "status": status,
            },
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(response) {
                $('.alert').show();

            }
        });
    });
```

Controller :

```
public function studentrefund(Request $request)
{

    $data = Refund::findOrFail($request->id);
    $data->status = $request->status;
    $data->save();

    return response()->json(['success'=>'Saved successfully.']);
}
```